# Python url matching for querystring

Tags: python

I need to match below two urls which are same. Only difference is between the order of query string parameters.

```
domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?**bb=cc&dd=ee**

domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?**dd=ee&bb=cc**
```

Is there any library in Python which could do this? If not what would be the best way to do it?

As of now I believe splitting and storing in dictionary and comparing would be the best way.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> d1 = 'domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?bb=cc&dd=ee'
>>> d2 = 'domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?dd=ee&bb=cc'
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(d1).query) == parse_qs(urlparse(d2).query)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `urllib.parse` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

```
from urllib import parse


parsed = parse.urlsplit('domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?bb=cc&dd=ee')
query_dict1 = parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)

parsed = parse.urlsplit('domain.com/base-path/sub_path/aaa?dd=ee&bb=cc')
query_dict2 = parse.parse_qs(p2.query)

print(query_dict1 == query_dict2)
```

Comment: why do you use urlsplit here..?

Comment: @oskros  As said [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit)  
```This is similar to urlparse(), but does not split the params from the URL. This should generally be used instead of urlparse() if the more recent URL syntax allowing parameters to be applied to each segment of the path portion of the URL (see RFC 2396) is wanted. A separate function is needed to separate the path segments and parameters.```  
May be I'm not right

Answer (score -1):

You just need to sort the parameters. One way to accomplish this could be

```
def get_params(url):
    return sorted(url.split("?")[-1])

get_params(url1) == get_params(url2)

True
```

Comment: You are sorting the query string not the components of the query.